# Export FileContentResult files to ZIP

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, zip

I use C#-MVC3. I have an "export" page. I have some functions for exporting different tables from the DB, every function creates a CSV file from the table and returns a FileContentResult file to the user.

Now I want to create a button for "export all", to download all the files at once.
I tried to use ZipFile but it gets only file names and path - files that were saved on the server, not "FileContentResult" files.

So I wanted to save the "FileContentResult" files temporarily on the server, zip them and delete them - but I can't find how to save a "FileContentResult" file.

If you can help me or give me another idea, I'll glad to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my solution:

```
    public ZipFile DownloadAllToZip()
    {
        string path = "c:\\TempCSV";
        try
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                EmptyFolder(path);
            }
            else
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            List<FileContentResult> filesToExport = GetAllCSVs();

            foreach (var file in filesToExport)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path + "\\" + file.FileDownloadName, FileMode.CreateNew))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = file.FileContents;
                            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        catch{ }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MaterialAssetTracker.zip");
        ZipFile zip= new ZipFile();
        using (zip)
        {
            zip.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.None;
            zip.AddSelectedFiles("*.csv", path + "\\", "", false);
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        Response.Close();
        EmptyFolder(path);
        return zip;
    }
```